# Route:list showed webpage exist, but only one webpage shows error 404

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller, laravel-blade

I understood this has been asked a lot of times.

When i run route:list it listed out every webpage correctly without target error.
However, all my webpages are working except the "ApplicationConfirmation" page upon clicking submiting from "ApplicationForm".

Note that everything is working fine until i pull an update from github, however, the update does not modify the web.php, or any of my controller or models or views that related to these two pages. So I doubt it has to do with this error. **Only ApplicationConfirmation page is not working**.

Heres the **route list output**

```
+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                                         | Name                            | Action
                                   | Middleware |
+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                                           |                                 | Closure
                                   | web        |
|        | POST     | ApplicationConfirmation                     | ApplicationConfirmation         | App\Http\Controllers\LeaveApplicationConfirmationController@passInput   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | ApplicationConfirmation/confirm             | ApplicationConfirmation/confirm | App\Http\Controllers\LeaveApplicationConfirmationController@storeDB     | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | ApplicationConfirmation/download/{filename} |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\LeaveApplicationConfirmationController@downloadDoc | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | ApplicationForm                             |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\LeaveApplicationFormController@index               | web        |
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('/ApplicationForm', 'App\Http\Controllers\LeaveApplicationFormController@index');
Route::get('/ApplicationConfirmation/confirm','App\Http\Controllers\LeaveApplicationConfirmationController@storeDB')->name('ApplicationConfirmation/confirm');
Route::get('/ApplicationConfirmation/download/{filename}', 'App\Http\Controllers\LeaveApplicationConfirmationController@downloadDoc');
Route::post('/ApplicationConfirmation','App\Http\Controllers\LeaveApplicationConfirmationController@passInput')->name('ApplicationConfirmation');
```

It will first access ApplicationForm, then from ApplicationForm, it will post to ApplicationConfirmation, then ApplicationConfirmation/confirm upon confirming the confirmation.

The url for application form (display successfully) is
`localhost/myProject/public/ApplicationForm`

The url after submitting the form and gives error is
`localhost/myProject/public/ApplicationConfirmation`

The html form on ApplicationForm is

```
<form action="{{route('ApplicationConfirmation')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
    <div class="row my-4"> .... form details
```

**Solutions I have tried**

1. php artisan route:clear
2. php artisan config:cache
3. php artisan cache:clear
4. composer dump-autoload
5. @csrf is included in application form

Comment: "is not working" ... what do you expect to happen and what is actually happening

Comment: @lagbox i explained what happened. I do not know how to further explain except the confirmation webpage giving 404. Hence, i'd like it to not be error 404 and actually showed the confirmation page after clicking submit button on the form page. They previously work until i pull the git update, ive tried revert the pull but it still shows the same error

The url after i click submit is 
localhost/myProject/public/ApplicationConfirmation

Comment: what URL is in the address bar when you get the 404?

Comment: Why is "myproject/public" in this url? `localhost/myProject/public/ApplicationConfirmation`? Can you show the html for the form thats being submitted?

Comment: @lagbox it is localhost/myProject/public/ApplicationConfirmation

Comment: @WesleySmith because i am saving this project in a folder called myProject in the XAMPP htdocs. Then i display the views by defining the web route in web.php. Sorry I misedit, i updated the correct code for html

Comment: you probably should be using virtual hosts so that your app is the root of the site .... laravel really isn't meant to be in a sub directory, btw

Comment: @lagbox hm, I see thanks for the advice, but does that really affect anything, as in the diff between storing it as sub dir and root? Since it previously work fine until I restarted my vscode and pulled an update from git.

Comment: Yeah, I've never had `public` in any of the urls for my apps. that folder is usually the web root and the index file serves up the routes from there. Im not sure how laravel will react in this setup, but its def not typical.

Comment: @WesleySmith to my experience, we have been storing laravel projects as sub dir, does not seem to have encountered such error. These are just college assignments, hence we never really configure a virtual host for it.

Comment: We're not saying it wont work, its just that it'll be harder to find help when something goes wrong (like now) because the projects are set up in a non-standard way. For what its worth, virtual hosts are quite easy to set up. IHMO, starting with a properly configured environment goes a long way towards avoiding issues. In any case, I hope you find an answer. :)